# Modify Keyword vs Modify Column Keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When modify table what is the difference between add `COLUMN` keyword and remove it

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TEXT;
```

**VS**

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `column_name` TEXT;
```

Comment: The `column` keyword is, I think optional, so they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Yes, `COLUMN` is an optional keyword. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

> The word `COLUMN` is optional and can be omitted, except for `RENAME COLUMN` (to distinguish a column-renaming operation from the `RENAME` table-renaming operation).

---

Thanks to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) for give me the answer